# How to substitute the variables in StringForm to an expression/function

Tags: string-manipulation, evaluation

I have some variables derived in `StringForm`. For example;

```
variables = StringForm["x=``,\[Delta]=``", 5, 10]
```

How to substitute the variables to an expression/function.

```
expr=\[Delta]*x];

 With[{variables}, expr//Evaluate]
```

When I evaluate the code, I get the following error:
[image]

**How to solve the error, I want to get 50 as follows:**

[image]

I think we should transform variables to a value (or plain ).

Comment: Why do you want to pass parameters as a `String`? I think there are better options like `Association`, or others.

Comment: I agree with @rhermans: this looks like a classic [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: The OP is likely asking for help in a way that obscures the real issue. We have seen long good answers that are likely to bring the OP in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a learning experience.

[image]

---

```
With[{v = variables},
 Echo[v, "v="];
 Echo[ToString@v, "string @v="];
 Echo[StringSplit[ToString@v, ","], "SSp @v="];
 ToExpression@StringSplit[ToString@v, ","];
 Echo[x, "x="];
 Echo[\[Delta], "\[Delta]="];
 expr = x \[Delta]
 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not quite clear, what do you want to achieve. It is always helpful if in the question one formulates the result he needs to get.

I understood the question such that you want to transform the `StringForm` into the expression. Then after the evaluation Mma will know that x is 5 and Delta is 10. Is it right? If yes, try the following.

Step  1: let us form two strings

```
str1 = StringTake[ToString[variables], 3];
str2 = StringTake[ToString[variables], 5 ;; 8];
```

So far, str1 and str2 are strings

```
str1
str2

(*  "x=5"

"\[Delta]=10"  *)
```

One can check it:

```
Head[str1]

(*  String  *)
```

Step 2:
Now, it is easy to transform them into expressions:

```
ToExpression[str1]
ToExpression[str2]

(*  5

10  *)
```

Let us check if Mma "knows" the values of x and Delta:

```
x
\[Delta]


 
   (* 5
    
    10  *)
```

**Edit**

Step 3:

```
expr = \[Delta]*x;
With[{x = ToExpression[str1],
  \[Delta] = ToExpression[str2]}, expr]

(*  50  *)
```

Done.

*Some explanations:*

1. The construct `With` requires the `Set` statement within the curly braces. That is, `With[{expr1=something1, expr2=something2}, expr3]`. Your variable `variables` does not have a form of the `Set` statement. This is reported to you as an error message.
2. The variable `variables` has a head `StringForm`. Please check `Head[variables]`. It is a specific form to work with texts. Using variables with such a head for standard calculations is possible (as I have shown) but strongly complicates the code. I generally recommend another way around. That is, making calculations in a usual way with standard variables, and then transforming these variables into strings when needed.

Hope it helps. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I edited the post. How to solve the error: ``With::lvws: Variable variables in local variable specification {variables} requires a value.``

Comment: @HD239  Please see the edits.